# jQuery scraping output in BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: jquery, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi,

I am scraping some data from a web page by using codes below.

```
import requests

    response = requests.get(my_link)

    html=response.text

import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    result=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

    print(result.prettify())
```

However,peculiarly, I got the output as below.

```
jQuery(
        {
            "xname":[
              {
                "number":"3792",
                "eic":"0",
                "code":"a"
                },

             {                                                

                "number":"1067",
                "eic":"1",       
                "code":"b"      
            }

             ],

            "yname":"max",
            "zname":{
                "opt1":"2",
                "opt2":"19"
            }


           }   
        );
```

I wanted to have a look at the data types by using codes;

```
type(result)
type(result.prettify())
```

and they gave me **bs4.BeautifulSoup** and **unicode** respectively. Actually I was expecting **.json** format data, since the output was looking like that but it is not!

So, could anyone tell me what sort of output is it? How can i get the data out from this result? (*i.e. number="3792", opt1="2"*)

Comment: please give the url that you're parsing

Comment: By lefting out the "jQuery(" string and  ");"  with using **re.sub**  function, data turned into a file that can be transformed into the json. So I solved the problem by this way.

Comment: @maydin If you solved your problem, it's recommended to post it as an answer and then wait and accept it, it makes it easier for users with similar problems to find the solution!